Make head and tail of a bone follow two different paths
I need the head an the tail of a bone to follow two separate paths while keeping the length of the bone fixed:

I tried all sorts of combinations of IK, Clamp to, and Limit distance. Is it possible to do this in Blender?

just use two bones with follow path and use track to from one bone to the other (this prerequisites, that your both paths are equidistant for every point)

@Chris, as you can see from the image, my paths are not parallel. What I need is for the bone to rotate as it slides
